# Macro to replace multiple words in a Microsoft Word document, including footnotes

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to replace multiple words in multiple Microsoft Word documents.  There is a list of words that must be redacted by replacement in each document.  Some of these documents have footnotes.

As an example, Mr Blue becomes Mr Falcon, Mr Red becomes Mr Eagle, etc.

As the list of names is long, using the standard find/replace would require running 19+ operations on each file, with a great deal of risk of mistakes.

I figured a Macro would be much more consistent.  I couldn't find a solution anywhere that handled both the document and footnotes, so I created one below based on code I found here and elsewhere.

NOTE:  I am asking and answering this question so that future users can solve this problem.  A working solution is below.

Comment: This forum expects that you will have a macro written, that you need  help with, not that you will expect someone else to write one for you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I answered the question myself below.  I posted this so that anyone else who had this problem could find the solutioin.

Comment: @Lindylead - that's great that you answered your own question, but the question itself doesn't fit here. It's a broad question with a set of high level requirements. If you want to write posts like this, I suggest considering a blog. For questions here, they need to be answering something specific.

Answer (score 2):

Solution:  Create the following Macro and run it against each file.

```
Sub MultiReplace()

Dim StrFind As String, StrRepl As String
Dim FindItem As String, ReplaceItem As String
Dim i As Long
Dim aNote As Endnote

StrFind = "Red, Green, Blue, Red, Yellow, 123, 456"
StrRepl = "Sparrow, Duck, Falcon, Eagle, Pigeon, ABC, 987"

Set RngTxt = Selection.Range

For i = 0 To UBound(Split(StrFind, ","))

    FindItem = Split(StrFind, ",")(i)
    ReplaceItem = Split(StrRepl, ",")(i)
    Selection.HomeKey wdStory
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
    
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = FindItem
        .Replacement.Text = ReplaceItem
        .Format = False
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    
    End With
    
    For Each aNote In ActiveDocument.Endnotes
        With aNote.Range
            
          .Find.Execute FindText:=FindItem, ReplaceWith:=ReplaceItem, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        
        End With
    Next aNote
Next i
End Sub
```

This code takes a list of search terms and replacement terms.  It then iterates through the terms, running search and replace against the document text.  It then loops through each footnote and does the same find/replace.

Comment: Aside from its inefficiency, your code won't find & replace content in textboxes, headers, footers, etc. To see how to do it properly, visit: https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/using_a_macro_to_replace_text_wherever_it_appears_in_a_document.html